# Nested select from two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

table A contain many ids, which one is related to the table B.

I have to make a query on the table A to select only some ids and then take the data from the table B using the selected ids from the table A

How can i do that? (MYSQL)

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: I have id_song from the table A in which i have many ids ad in the pic https://upload.picpaste.me/image/j1eGj
that ids references the id from the table B in the pic 
https://upload.picpaste.me/image/j11Yc

I need to select id_song who satisfy my requirements from table A and join the ids with the other data from the table B

Comment: @VincenzoD'Errico that's not helpful , please don't paste screenshots in comments , provide reusable sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, here is a simple structure of how the query might go, although I recommend you share some sample results & the desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
JOIN tableB
ON tableA.id_song == tableB.id_song
WHERE "your condition HERE"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i got another problem, which is more painful. 
I got a table named midi_request which is in that form: